# python boto3 doesn't return some valid dynamoDB records

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am using boto3 to scan a DynamoDB table to find records with a certain ID (articleID or imageID).

For some valid articleIDs the scan returns zero results. If I do the scan with the exact same articleID in the DynamoDB console, it works fine. Through boto3, zero results. If I pick another articleID, the results return as expected.

For the records that don't return, it also won't return using the imageID. For the record that does work, it works for either ID. I can't see any difference between the records. The only thing I can think of is that the ones that don't work time out, but is there a setting for that in boto3?

Table name  articleImages
Primary partition key   imageID (String)
Primary sort key    articleID (String)

PYTHON

```
db = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
imageTable = db.Table('articleImages')
articleID = "Xxp6ntkoUnX4NDEqn8gSVo" #THIS DOESNT WORK HERE BUT DOES IN CONSOLE
articleID = "EqVxu2tcP7EavFGPDw7R5A" # THIS ONE WORKS HERE
response = imageTable.scan(
FilterExpression=Attr('articleID').eq(articleID)
)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: A couple of questions
1. Assuming your boto scan returns some records in certain cases?
2. What happens if you hard code the criteria e.g. FilterExpression=Attr('articleID').eq("Xxp6ntkoUnX4NDEqn8gSVo")?

Comment: Hi, 1) yes, some IDs work fine (such as the second one provided in the code example), 2) I tried that but the result is the same.

Comment: A couple of suggestions to try

1. Try using Query vs Scan. 
2. Try setting the ConsistentRead=True when reading

Comment: thanks, 1) Query requires the key and i only have the sort key. If i use the key and query, it does work, i just don't have it in the use case. 2) i tried consistentRead=True and no change.

Comment: i tried .contains and the same result. One thing I noticed is that the ScannedCount on both attempts is much less than the item count in the table, about half. So my guess is that it is not scanning the whole table.

Comment: I still don't know how to fix the scan situation, but I fixed my use case by adding a secondary index for the sort key and just using a query on that. Not sure what the point of a sort key is now.

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior